# EF Core + Postgres - Hashset?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm currently translating some code from Redis to Postgres, and one thing I'm not sure how to deal with is sets/hash sets.

I need to extract "tags" and store them as some form of set.
a unique tag should only exist once per set.

For Redis, this is built in, there are set types.
But for Postgres, what can I use here?
Having a table with each tag as a row/record and then constantly checking if that tag exists and if not inserting it, would be too slow for this specific use-case.
The Usecase is service observability/traces/metrics/logs, so there will be plenty of data at high frequency arriving

What are my options here?

I could of course keep a cache in memory and ignore existing tags there. to avoid having to check the DB.

But I was hoping there would be some nice built-in way to deal with this in Postgres.
e.g. a set-like table of some sort.

Even better if there is something that is compatible with EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what you need is a *unique key* in your relational database. This would raise an exception in case of duplicate tags (when trying to insert a Tag that already exists)

If you were using Nhibernate it would handle that for you, but I think EF would too.

PostgreSql offers the upsert concept also. See this:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-upsert/

If you can't have custom inserts with EF you could create a stored procedure that uses the Upsert and call it from EF.